# OneToOne relationship does not delete child

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

After 6 hours of debuggin its time for stackoverflow X)
I have the following classes:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "publicProfileDancer" )
@Data
public class PublicProfileDancer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne( mappedBy = "publicProfileDancer", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true )
    private State state;
    ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "state" )
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class State {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    @Basic
    @Column( name = "statesID" )
    private Long statesID;

    @Basic
    @Column( name = "name" )
    private String name;

    @OneToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @JoinColumn( name = "publicProfileDancer_id" )
    private PublicProfileDancer publicProfileDancer;
}
```

**My Code:**

```
@Transaction
public User mapPublicUser( PublicUserDTO publicUserDTO, User userEntity ) {
    if ( publicUserDTO == null ) return null;

    PublicProfileDancer publicProfile;
    if(userEntity.getPublicProfileDancer() != null){
        publicProfile = userEntity.getPublicProfileDancer();
    }else{
        publicProfile = new PublicProfileDancer();
        publicProfile.setUser( userEntity );
        userEntity.setPublicProfileDancer( publicProfile );
    }

    publicProfile.setState( stateMapper.map( publicUserDTO.getState(), publicProfile ) );

    publicProfile.setValue1("Anthing else");
    ... //some other column settings in publicProfile
   
    return userEntity;
}
```

This is the stateMapper:

```
public State map( StateDTO stateDTO, PublicProfileDancer publicDancer  ) {
    if ( stateDTO == null ) return null;

    State stateEntity = new State();
    stateEntity.setStatesID( stateDTO.getStatesID() );
    stateEntity.setName( stateDTO.getName() );
    stateEntity.setCountryId( stateDTO.getCountryId() );
    stateEntity.setCountryName( stateDTO.getCountryName() );
    stateEntity.setPublicProfileDancer( publicDancer );

    return stateEntity;
}
```

The code above works to save **ONE** state.

**Two scenarios now:**

**First**: I try to delete this state again with setting state to null:

```
publicProfile.setState( null ); //stateMapper would return null;
```

I get the following error message:
*javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations)*

**Second**: I try to overwrite the state saved in the db with antoher state.

```
publicProfile.setState( state ); //stateMapper would return a new state
```

I dont get an error message but I have two entries in the db.

What is wrong?

Comment: How are you reading in the publicProfile and then saving it after nulling out the state reference? As for "instead of overwriting, as second state is created" that seems like you are creating a new State instance instead of using and modifying the one already associated. Doing so, with orphan removal, should cause JPA to delete the existing state and create a new one with the new state. If you want to use the existing one and merge state overtop, make sure you are setting the entity ID values (if using REST/JSON) to ensure the entities can be matched up.

Comment: @Chris I have updated my topic. I am using "@Transaction" to save the entities. I explicity do not want to update the child. I want to create a new State instance and save only that new one in the database.

Comment: What do you mean State cannot be deleted - what errors do you get, and what are you doing to 'try' to delete a State instance?  How are you now getting this userEntity instance and how is JPA expected to pick up changes to it's referenced PublicProfileDancer and that graph? Are you intending to have JPA replace state with a new instance every time mapPublicUser is called and PublicProfileDancer already exists for that user?

Comment: The map function in the answer is odd - it is nulling out the State's fk value, and you are then going to set the publicProfile.setState reference to a completely new State instance. If you are getting an error telling you a deleted object would be re-saved by a casade, it means you have other references to these objects in the question that you are not showing us. You CANNNOT mark something to be removed via orphan removal and leave other objects in your graph referencing it still that might have a cascade persist/merge on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a long time but I was able to solve it. I changed my entity "State" to `@MapsId` and adjusted my code as follows.

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "publicProfileDancer" )
@Data
public class PublicProfileDancer {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne( mappedBy = "publicProfileDancer", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true )
    private State state;

    //... some more properties
}
```

My State class with the new `@MapsId` annotation:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "state" )
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class State {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @OneToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @MapsId
    private PublicProfileDancer publicProfileDancer;

    //... some more properties
}
```

My code:

```
publicProfile.setState( stateMapper.map( publicUserDTO.getState(), publicProfile ) );
```

with the stateMapper function:

```
public State map( StateDTO stateDTO, PublicProfileDancer publicDancer  ) {
    if ( stateDTO == null ) {
        if(publicDancer.getState() != null){
            publicDancer.getState().setPublicProfileDancer( null );
        }
        return null;
    }

    State stateEntity;
    if(publicDancer.getState() != null){
        stateEntity = publicDancer.getState();
    }else{
        stateEntity = new State();
    }

    stateEntity.setStatesID( stateDTO.getStatesID() );
    stateEntity.setName( stateDTO.getName() );
    stateEntity.setCountryId( stateDTO.getCountryId() );
    stateEntity.setCountryName( stateDTO.getCountryName() );
    stateEntity.setPublicProfileDancer( publicDancer );

    return stateEntity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

may be

```
    public State map( StateDTO stateDTO, PublicProfileDancer publicDancer  ) {
        if ( stateDTO == null ) return null;
        if (publicDancer.getState() != null)     publicDancer.getState().setPublicProfileDancer(null);
    
        State stateEntity = new State();
        stateEntity.setStatesID( stateDTO.getStatesID() );
        stateEntity.setName( stateDTO.getName() );
        stateEntity.setCountryId( stateDTO.getCountryId() );
        stateEntity.setCountryName( stateDTO.getCountryName() );
        stateEntity.setPublicProfileDancer( publicDancer );
    
        return stateEntity;
    }
```

Comment: Sadly not. I tried that already, but then I get the error message "deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations)"

Comment: I think you should use JoinColumn on parent Entity, not child.


@JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "publicProfileDancer_id")

Comment: This is because we only *need it on the owning side of the foreign key relationship*. Simply put, whoever owns the foreign key column gets the @JoinColumn annotation.
https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-one-to-one